# AnyObject is not a subtype of SIOParameterArray

Tags: swift

I use SIOSocket connect to the NodeJs ,this is my code

> SIOSocket.socketWithHost("XXXXXXXXXX",  response: {
> (socket:SIOSocket!)  in
>
> ```
>   self.socket = socket;
>   self.socket.on("move", callback: { (args:SIOParameterArray)  in
>       println("aaa")
>   })
> ```
>
> })

but there is a error in line

```
self.socket.on("move", callback: { (args:SIOParameterArray) in
'[AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'SIOParameterArray'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SIOParameterArray` is just a alias of `NSArray`.
So, this Objective-C definition:

```
typedef NSArray SIOParameterArray

@interface SIOSocket : NSObject
- (void)on:(NSString *)event callback:(void (^)(SIOParameterArray *args))function;
@end
```

is identical to:

```
@interface SIOSocket : NSObject
- (void)on:(NSString *)event callback:(void (^)(NSArray *args))function;
@end
```

And it's translated to Swift as:

```
class SIOSocket : NSObject {
    func on(event: String!, callback function: (([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!)
}
```

So, you can use `[AnyObject]!` as the compiler says:

```
SIOSocket.socketWithHost("XXXXXXXXXX", response: { (socket:SIOSocket!) in

    self.socket = socket;
    self.socket.on("move", callback: { (args:[AnyObject]!)  in
        println("aaa")
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback argument is an Optional `SIOParameterArray`, not an `SIOParameterArray`.

So you need to write

```
  self.socket.on("move", callback: { (args:SIOParameterArray!)  in
```

if you want it to unwrap implicitely or

```
  self.socket.on("move", callback: { (args:SIOParameterArray?)  in
```

if you want the Optional itself